How to use PowerShell to modify Windows Defender Firewall Inbound rules
I'm trying to make a PowerShell script that can be run during computer setup to set all the most common settings we expect on our organization's workstations. One of those settings is the "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In" (and ICMPv6) found in Windows Defender Firewall's inbound rules to allow a device to be pinged. I want to limit enabling the ICMPv4 and ICMPv6 rules that are in the "Domain" profile, and not the "Private" profile, but I'm having a hard time nailing down the Domain rule and not the Private rule. I'm testing Get-NetFirewallRule to see if I can narrow it down to the specific rule before passing it to Set-NetFirewallRule to actually make the change.
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" gets 4 entries, two private and two domain. I was hoping there was a "-profile" parameter, but there doesn't seem to be for the "Get-" command... there is for the "Set-".
I tried piping the results of "Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Domain" into the above script to proactively limit the rules to those with the Domain profile, but that returns an error:
"Get-NetFirewallRule : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input." Reversing the pipes throws 4 errors (I assume because it's passing the 4 entries from above).
Maybe there's an easier way of doing this that I'm unfamiliar with (I'm an amateur at best), but any insight would be appreciated! I'd prefer to stick to PowerShell to build everything in one script. If there's any insight on the difference between enabling "Domain/Any" Profile/Remote Addresses as opposed to "Private/Local Subnet", I'd appreciate that too.

set-netfirewallrule -profile domain or get-netfirewallrule | ? profile -eq domain | set-netfirewallrule -whatif

@js2010 - I tried "Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" -Profile Domain -Enabled True", and it took one of the four entries, one of the "private" profile ones, and overwrote it with "Domain" and enabled it. Not quite what I was looking for... I wanted to modify an existing Domain profile rule. I'll test that other scirpt, though! Thanks for responding!

@js2010 - Using Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" | ? profile -eq domain | set-netfirewallrule -whatif returned What if: Set-NetFirewallRule DisplayName: FPS-ICMP4-ERQ-In-NoScope What if: Set-NetFirewallRule DisplayName: {6D0ABC6E-2CB6-44A3-BA8C-41A3838F64C3} Those are indeed the two entries with the display profile.
